# How to lookup value of table using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a hidden table on an asp webpage I can use to look up values from using jquery. Basically I have an ID that I want to match against the hidden table and then lookup the value 3 columns over from that ID. 
How would I do that?

All I see are results for getting the value of a clicked cell. But the user does not interact with my table.

Also, I'm using this structure to avoid repeated calls to the server. I am gathering the data into a table all at once and then I want to be able to search it using jquery.

Comment: Why are you storing data in html?  you can just make a javascript object with your data?  Can you explain your requirements a bit more?

Comment: It would be much better to store the data in a JavaScript object, this wouldn't require an extra call to the server.

Comment: Basically I have a 20 x 40 SQL dataset that is being used to fill in 3 textboxes in a control. The values of those textboxes need to change frequently. Instead of making repeated calls to the server for those new values, I am trying to gather the whole SQL dataset on page load and then look up values when the 3 textboxes need to be changed.

Comment: Ok I will research how to do that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question might be a case of an XY problem - instead of using a HTML `<table>` that is not visible, you might want to construct an array of JavaScript objects instead. (However, I am not sure whether this approach is actually preferable over yours, and its performance might depend on whether the data you want to store is relatively small or relatively big.)

But if you want to go on with your approach, you can decorate your `<tr>` elements with `data-whatever` attribute (and `<td>` with `data-something`) like so:

```
<tr data-number="@put-id-in-here">
     <td data-column="firstName">John</td>
     <td data-column="lastName">Smith</td>
</tr>
```

and when you want to get the last name from 42nd row, you can use jQuery like this:

```
$("#idOfYourTable")
    .find("tr[data-number=42]")
    .find("td[data-column=lastName]")
    .text();//or whatever jQuery function you desire
```

Alternatively, if don't want to add any attributes, you can probably make do with [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to select elements by their position inside their parent elements.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot. So far my research on using Javascript objects has pointed me to using PHP and MySQL, and I'm currently using neither of those so this looks like the better method for me right now

Comment: @anesthetic I see. PHP+database and JS solve different problems - former is for generating HTML pages before sending it to user's browser over the net, latter is for allowing browser to perform operations for user's convenience (like better UX). The argument for using JS array of objects instead of a hidden HTML table is that if the data is only ever accessed by JS anyway, it will be both faster (performance-wise, since jQuery doesn't has to process DOM) and easier (for the developer) to put it inside a JS variable.

Comment: Is there a good resource you can link me to? I'm on the 4th page of google for a few searches now and I'm having trouble finding an example of making a JS array from a MSSQL table

Comment: @anesthetic Unfortunately, I don't have any tutorials handy. (If you're having a lot of trouble, why not ask another question here on StackOverflow?) The basic idea is that, instead of creating HTML markup like `<tr><td><?php echo $lastName; ?></td></tr>`, you create Javascript markup like `tableArray.push(new { id: <?php echo $id; ?>, lastName:"<?php echo $lastName; ?>"});`. See here for [working with JS objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp) and see [here for JS arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).